# Calling a function from within a nested directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am somewhat new to Angular so please forgive me if I screw up some of the terminology.  I am passing a function to a directive, which in turn, is trying to pass it to another directive.  The function can be called from within the first directive (not what I need), but not the second directive (what I need).  Both of the directives have isolate scope, which is why I'm passing the function down like this.

```
<first-directive my-func="myFunc({value: theValue})">
   <second-directive my-func="myFunc({value: theValue})"></second-directive>
</first-directive>
```

Is it possible to do this?  If not, what is the best approach, should I just require the controller in the "second" directive so that I have access to this function?

Comment: Where is the `theValue` defined?

Comment: "theValue" is defined in the the link function of the second directive

Comment: See http://plnkr.co/edit/yLdQt1n1sl02fQWl89pv?p=previewg

Comment: can you share the both directive's code...

Comment: Thanks @runTarm, your plunker helped me see what I was missing.  In my "first" directive I'm trying to compile my "second" directive, but in that html string I was writing "myFunc(value)" instead of "myFunc({value: theValue})".